# Ruby on Rails app planning - login system routing when not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm building a rails app, and so far I've set up a pretty basic user registration/login system, mainly by following this [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) I found thanks to stack overflow. I've left everything the same as the railcast, only used strong parameters instead of attr_accessible and added some additional fields (username, bio, img url) to the table.

Now I want my app to redirect users onto my login page if they're not logged in, no matter what page they try to access, and if they are, then redirect to the normal path. My loging page is currently my root_path. Do I need to do this in all the controllers separately or can I just write this into my appController? How would I go about writing the controller? I was thinking something like this:

```
if session[:user_id] == nil 
  redirect_to login_path
else
  redirect_to current_controller_path
end
```

Now how do I check if user is logged in, and how do I redirect to current controller path (for instance articles_index_path?

I am new to ruby on rails, and still trying to wrap my head around models, views and controllers, so please assume I know nothing when writing up explanations :) Thanks for the help

Oh I'm using Rails 4 with ruby 2.2.1

Comment: You should extract your 2nd doubt (thats a good ques) which is regarding memory usage from this question to new one. Like this, other users will be able to get benefit from both the questions. Here its getting faded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController` to check user's authentication.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  ...
  private
  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to login_path unless session[:user_id]
  end
end
```

Now it will make sure that user should be logged in for accessing any action of any controller, including signup, signin and other actions which should be accessible to non-logged in users too.

You need to make sure that you skip above `before_filter` where you don't want user to be logged in such as signup, signin, about us, contact us etc actions like this.

For Example:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => :destroy
  ...

  def new
    ...
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

You can read more about `skip_before_filter` on [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/skip_before_filter)

Comment: I am now getting `undefined method `authenticate_user!' for ApplicationController:Class` . I'll edit my controller into the main post, if you can spot something obvious.

Comment: There was missing colon. `authenticate_user!` should be `:authenticate_user!`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated it and it works. Also edited the question in the way you proposed, will open new one about the @current_user variable in a bit, gotta google it some more first. I've also deleted the code you provided from the original question, no use posting it twice.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped you. Thanks for considering the suggestion. Kindly acknowledge it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575648/ruby-on-rails-app-planning-login-system-routing-when-not-logged-in/29576068#comment47300949_29575648 You may want to add link to new question in your acknowledgement